# Set hidden input type from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, hidden-field

I am working on a ASP.NET project. Currently, on "Change Name" button, following client method is called and form is submitted. This method is updating a hidden field "hdnUpdateName". I need to now set from server-side instead of client-side.

```
function ChangeNameClick()
            {
                document.getElementById('hdnUpdateName').value = "true";
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
```

Change Name button is a server-side control as below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnChangeName" runat="server" OnClientClick="ChangeNameClick()"/>
```

And form looks like below:

```
<form id="MainForm" method="post" runat="server" novalidate>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnUpdateName" runat="server" value="false" />
    .
    .
    .
    .............some other fields.....
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

I need to first update the hidden parameter and then submit the form.

I know how to set hidden parameter from server-side, but don't know how to make sure form submit should occur after hidden parameter update only.

Can someone please guide how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but you could eventually put a timeout after you place the hidden attribute.

Try something like this :

```
    function ChangeNameClick()
                {
                        document.getElementById('hdnUpdateName').value = "true";
                        var millisecondsToWait = 100;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                             document.forms[0].submit();
                        }, millisecondsToWait);
                }
```